# VSCode: Format terminal output to break on each entry in list

Tags: visual-studio-code

Is there a way to alter my terminal output in VSCode such that the following:

```
l1 = ['/mnt/path/folder/folder2/folder3/*.parquet', '/mnt/path/folder/folder2/folder3/*.parquet']
```

When executed yields the following in the terminal:

```
['/mnt/path/folder/folder2/folder3/*.parquet',
 '/mnt/path/folder/folder2/folder3/*.parquet']
```

Rather than:

```
['/mnt/path/folder/folder2/folder3/*.parquet', '/mnt/path/folder/folder2/folder3/*.parquet']
```

Comment: write a filter program that modifies the input how you want and then ouputs it, use this in a `|` construct

Comment: Any other hints on what I might search for, rather than vscode filter program, to learn more about this?

Comment: it is Python/C/JavaScript/Rust/.... program that alters input and dumps it on output

Comment: it is how all UNIX commands work, on the terminal command line you pipe the output to a command/filter (like `head`, `tail`, `xargs`, `sed`, `awk` ....)